# Divisor question on the normal projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

> Let $X$ a normal projective curve over an infinite field $k$, let
> $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be pairwise distinct closed points in $X$ and let
> $n_1,\dots,n_r\in\mathbb Z$. Let $$D=\sum_in_ix_i$$ (considered as a
> Cariter divisor).
>
> Let $y\in X$ be a closed point distinct from all the
> $x_i$. Show that for large enough $n$, we have $$L(D+ny) \ne \bigcup_iL(D+ny-x_i).$$

It is the Ex7.3.2 a) from the book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves by Qing Liu. I add the following qusetions.

1. If we treat $D$ as a Weil divisor, what is the difference?
2. It seems that if $n$ is not large enough, we may have $$L(D+ny) =\cup_iL(D+ny-x_i),$$ some gap phenomenon？How to explian it?

Comment: (1) There is no difference, as Weil divisors are also Cartier on a normal curve.  (2) It can happen that $L(D+ny)=L(D+ny-x_i)$ for some $i\le r$.

Comment: I see， the Riemann-Roch Theorem can solve this question.